# C# Set value and parse to class

Tags: c#

I'm  need to send string id (for example: 13) to class dbConnect, where I will use the id to delete row with this id. I don't know how to send this value, I hope that you can help me, thanks.

```
if (dgDisplay.SelectedCells.Count > 0)
{
    int selectedrowindex = dgDisplay.SelectedCells[0].RowIndex;

    DataGridViewRow selectedRow = dgDisplay.Rows[selectedrowindex];

    string id = Convert.ToString(selectedRow.Cells["ciD"].Value);


        DialogResult dialogResult = MessageBox.Show("Do you want to delete link? - ID:" + id, "Delete link", MessageBoxButtons.YesNo, MessageBoxIcon.Question);
        if (dialogResult == DialogResult.Yes)
        {

            dbConnect.Delete();
        }
        else if (dialogResult == DialogResult.No)
        {
            //do something else
        }


}
```

*dgDisplay = DataGridView

Comment: And what is `dbConnect`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming dbConnect to be some sort of business manager or repository, you only need to add the parameter to the `Delete` method:

```
class DbConnect{
    public void Delete(string id){
        //Your delete implementation based on id parameter
    }
}
```

> Usage:

```
string id = Convert.ToString(selectedRow.Cells["ciD"].Value);
//...
if (dialogResult == DialogResult.Yes)
{
    dbConnect.Delete(id);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use Int32.Parse(id) and pass the returning value to your delete function.